# Is it possible to fit an image into path and give it perspective?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

Is it possible to fit an image into path and give it perspective? I can't do it. Css properties perspective, rotateY does not react.

```
perspective: 1000px; transform: rotateY(50deg);
```

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/kushnir22/pen/YzwmPRb)

That is, I want the user to draw, for example, some kind of surface on the house and load the texture into it. So far it turns out and I don't understand how to turn this texture in perspective -

[image]

Tell me please how this can be done? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Firefox supports this, Chrome doesn't. If you want to support Chrome you'd have to do the 3D perspective calculations yourself.

Comment: @RobertLongson, what you mean 'calculations  yourself'? Сan you explain in more detail?

Comment: write javascript code to apply a 3D transform to each path vertex, thereby constructing a new path.

Answer (score 2):

There are no 3D transforms in SVG yet (AFAIK) - so to do what you want you will need to invert your solution - by using a CSS transform on a HTML image and then clipping it using a clip path defined in SVG. Like so.

```css
#perspective-container {
  clip-path: url("#fake-clip")
}

#img1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  left: -100px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="perspective-container">
<img id="img1" src="https://images.vector-images.com/clp/185940/clp244232.jpg" >
</div>


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="500" >
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="fake-clip">
      <path class="path" d="M 94,15 221,95 220,247 29,210 29,97 Z" fill="white" stroke="#e46713"></path>
    </clipPath>
      </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you, very much!